# Android UE4 ERROR Missing precompiled manifest for 'SteamShared'

Tags: android, c++, c, unreal-engine4, steam

I've been building a game in c++ using the the `Unreal Engine 4 platform`. I've been using the following tools and plugins:

- Unreal Engine v4.24.3
- Steam Shared Module v1.0 plugin
- Online Subsystem Steam v1.1 plugin
- Steam VR v1.0 plugin

I am able to run the game locally and package it for windows. As soon as I try to launch it on my mobile phone or package it for android it throws the following error:

```
    LogPlayLevel:   Compiling Native code with NDK API 'android-19'
    LogPlayLevel: Error:   ERROR: Missing precompiled manifest for 'SteamShared'. This module was most likely not flagged for being included in a precompiled build - set 'PrecompileForTargets = PrecompileTargetsType.Any;' in SteamShared.build.cs to override.
    LogPlayLevel: Took 8.1195446s to run UnrealBuildTool.exe, ExitCode=5
```

Note that this was working before implementing the above stated plugins.

I proceeded to modify my steam plugin within my engine directory to meet the errors request but it did not change anything after rebuilding as seen
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3sSDM.png)

I then looked into my logs and found the below stack trace:

```
AndroidPlatform.SetUpSpecificEnvironment: PLATFORM_ANDROID_NDK_VERSION = 140200
AndroidPlatform.SetUpSpecificEnvironment: NDK toolchain: r14b, NDK version: 19, GccVersion: 4.9, ClangVersion: 3.8.275480
UnrealBuildTool.Main: ERROR: Missing precompiled manifest for 'SteamShared'. This module was most likely not flagged for being included in a precompiled build - set 'PrecompileForTargets = PrecompileTargetsType.Any;' in SteamShared.build.cs to override.
UnrealBuildTool.Main: BuildException: Missing precompiled manifest for 'SteamShared'. This module was most likely not flagged for being included in a precompiled build - set 'PrecompileForTargets = PrecompileTargetsType.Any;' in SteamShared.build.cs to override.
UnrealBuildTool.Main:    at UnrealBuildTool.UEBuildModuleCPP.Compile(ReadOnlyTargetRules Target, UEToolChain ToolChain, CppCompileEnvironment BinaryCompileEnvironment, FileReference SingleFileToCompile, ISourceFileWorkingSet WorkingSet, TargetMakefile Makefile) in D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Saved\CsTools\Engine\Source\Programs\UnrealBuildTool\Configuration\UEBuildModuleCPP.cs:line 277
UnrealBuildTool.Main:    at UnrealBuildTool.UEBuildBinary.SetupBinaryLinkEnvironment(ReadOnlyTargetRules Target, UEToolChain ToolChain, LinkEnvironment LinkEnvironment, CppCompileEnvironment CompileEnvironment, FileReference SingleFileToCompile, ISourceFileWorkingSet WorkingSet, DirectoryReference ExeDir, TargetMakefile Makefile) in D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Saved\CsTools\Engine\Source\Programs\UnrealBuildTool\Configuration\UEBuildBinary.cs:line 708
UnrealBuildTool.Main:    at UnrealBuildTool.UEBuildBinary.Build(ReadOnlyTargetRules Target, UEToolChain ToolChain, CppCompileEnvironment CompileEnvironment, LinkEnvironment LinkEnvironment, FileReference SingleFileToCompile, ISourceFileWorkingSet WorkingSet, DirectoryReference ExeDir, TargetMakefile Makefile) in D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Saved\CsTools\Engine\Source\Programs\UnrealBuildTool\Configuration\UEBuildBinary.cs:line 186
UnrealBuildTool.Main:    at UnrealBuildTool.UEBuildTarget.Build(BuildConfiguration BuildConfiguration, ISourceFileWorkingSet WorkingSet, Boolean bIsAssemblingBuild, FileReference SingleFileToCompile) in D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Saved\CsTools\Engine\Source\Programs\UnrealBuildTool\Configuration\UEBuildTarget.cs:line 1697
UnrealBuildTool.Main:    at UnrealBuildTool.BuildMode.CreateMakefile(BuildConfiguration BuildConfiguration, TargetDescriptor TargetDescriptor, ISourceFileWorkingSet WorkingSet) in D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Saved\CsTools\Engine\Source\Programs\UnrealBuildTool\Modes\BuildMode.cs:line 450
UnrealBuildTool.Main:    at UnrealBuildTool.BuildMode.Build(List`1 TargetDescriptors, BuildConfiguration BuildConfiguration, ISourceFileWorkingSet WorkingSet, BuildOptions Options, FileReference WriteOutdatedActionsFile) in D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Saved\CsTools\Engine\Source\Programs\UnrealBuildTool\Modes\BuildMode.cs:line 220
UnrealBuildTool.Main:    at UnrealBuildTool.BuildMode.Execute(CommandLineArguments Arguments) in D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Saved\CsTools\Engine\Source\Programs\UnrealBuildTool\Modes\BuildMode.cs:line 192
UnrealBuildTool.Main:    at UnrealBuildTool.UnrealBuildTool.Main(String[] ArgumentsArray) in D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Saved\CsTools\Engine\Source\Programs\UnrealBuildTool\UnrealBuildTool.cs:line 517
Timeline.Print: Timeline:
Timeline.Print: 
Timeline.Print: [ 0.000]
Timeline.Print: [ 0.000](+0.022) <unknown>
Timeline.Print: [ 0.022](+0.002) FileMetadataPrefetch.QueueEngineDirectory()
Timeline.Print: [ 0.025](+0.162) XmlConfig.ReadConfigFiles()
Timeline.Print: [ 0.187](+0.000) SingleInstanceMutex.Acquire()
Timeline.Print: [ 0.187](+0.145) UEBuildPlatform.RegisterPlatforms()
Timeline.Print:   0.188          [ 0.001](+0.079) Initializing InstalledPlatformInfo
Timeline.Print:   0.267          [ 0.080](+0.000) Querying types
Timeline.Print:   0.272          [ 0.085](+0.002) MacPlatformFactory
Timeline.Print:   0.275          [ 0.087](+0.000) TVOSPlatformFactory
Timeline.Print:   0.275          [ 0.087](+0.045) AndroidPlatformFactory
Timeline.Print:   0.320          [ 0.133](+0.000) HoloLensPlatformFactory
Timeline.Print:   0.321          [ 0.133](+0.004) IOSPlatformFactory
Timeline.Print:   0.325          [ 0.138](+0.003) LinuxPlatformFactory
Timeline.Print:   0.329          [ 0.142](+0.000) LuminPlatformFactory
Timeline.Print:   0.330          [ 0.142](+0.003) WindowsPlatformFactory
Timeline.Print: [ 0.333](+0.021) <unknown>
Timeline.Print: [ 0.355](+0.020) TargetDescriptor.ParseCommandLine()
Timeline.Print: [ 0.375](+0.022) <unknown>
Timeline.Print: [ 0.397](+0.636) UEBuildTarget.Create()
Timeline.Print:   0.401          [ 0.003](+0.203) RulesCompiler.CreateTargetRulesAssembly()
Timeline.Print:   0.401            0.003          [ 0.000](+0.093) <unknown>
Timeline.Print:   0.494            0.096          [ 0.093](+0.029) Finding engine modules
Timeline.Print:   0.523            0.126          [ 0.122](+0.012) Finding plugin modules
Timeline.Print:   0.536            0.138          [ 0.134](+0.058) <unknown>
Timeline.Print:   0.595            0.197          [ 0.193](+0.003) Finding program modules
Timeline.Print:   0.598            0.200          [ 0.196](+0.001) Finding program targets
Timeline.Print:   0.605          [ 0.207](+0.026) RulesAssembly.CreateTargetRules()
Timeline.Print:   0.632          [ 0.234](+0.023) <unknown>
Timeline.Print:   0.655          [ 0.257](+0.035) UEBuildTarget constructor
Timeline.Print:   0.662            0.264          [ 0.006](+0.027) Reading source file metadata cache
Timeline.Print:   0.690          [ 0.293](+0.343) UEBuildTarget.PreBuildSetup()
Timeline.Print: [ 1.038](+0.156) UEBuildTarget.Build()
Timeline.Print:   1.038          [ 0.000](+0.052) <unknown>
Timeline.Print:   1.090          [ 0.052](+0.035) ExternalExecution.SetupUObjectModules()
Timeline.Print:   1.125          [ 0.087](+0.024) <unknown>
Timeline.Print:   1.150          [ 0.111](+0.003) ExternalExecution.UpdateDirectoryTimestamps()
Timeline.Print:   1.167          [ 0.129](+0.026) UEBuildBinary.Build()
Timeline.Print: [ 1.194](+0.035) <unknown>
Timeline.Print: [ 1.229](+0.000) FileMetadataPrefetch.Stop()
Timeline.Print: [ 1.231]
```

Also my main project build.cs file has these modules being used:

`PublicDependencyModuleNames.AddRange(new string[] { "Core", "CoreUObject", "Engine", "InputCore", "HeadMountedDisplay", "UMG", "OnlineSubsystem", "OnlineSubsystemSteam" })`

If anyone has ran into this issue or requires more information please let me know, I am stumped at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem. I removed "OnlineSubsystem", "OnlineSubsystemUtils" from Build.cs